# I need to add the running count of one column into a second column

Tags: sql-server

Hi I would like to add the running count of col1 into col2

```
Col1     Col2
2        1
2        2
2        3
2        4
3        1
3        2
4        1
4        2
4        3
5        1
5        2
```

I have this query that does give me a running count and puts it into ResItem

```
SELECT afvol_internalid,
       RESBL_MATNR_Material,
       RESBL_SORTF_SortString,
       afvol_internalid AS ResNum,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY afvol_internalid ORDER BY afvol_internalid) AS ResItem
FROM [LOIPRO].[RESBL_PhaseMaterial]
WHERE RESBL_RSPOS_ReservationItem IS NULL
ORDER BY afvol_internalid;
```

Now I just need a way to get the results of ResItem into col2

Comment: How does the query you have relate to the sample data you provided? Neither `Col1` or `Col2` are referenced in the statement. The above doesn't "put the value into `ResItem`", it returns the row number and the column has an **alias** of `ResItem`; the stored value of `ResItem` (if that column exists in your table) hasn't changed.

Comment: The afvol_internalid would be col1 and my query does put the result into of that count into an alias called ResItem. I would instead like to put the result into another column in the same table say called col2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to a `primary key` to the table. Here is the SQL code

First let's create the table

```
CREATE TABLE tblData1 (
    id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    Col1 int NOT NULL,
    Col2 int NULL
 );

 INSERT INTO tblData1 (Col1) VALUES (1);
 INSERT INTO tblData1 (Col1) VALUES (1);
 INSERT INTO tblData1 (Col1) VALUES (2);
 INSERT INTO tblData1 (Col1) VALUES (2);
 INSERT INTO tblData1 (Col1) VALUES (2);
 INSERT INTO tblData1 (Col1) VALUES (3);
 INSERT INTO tblData1 (Col1) VALUES (3);
 INSERT INTO tblData1 (Col1) VALUES (4);
 INSERT INTO tblData1 (Col1) VALUES (4);
 INSERT INTO tblData1 (Col1) VALUES (5);
 INSERT INTO tblData1 (Col1) VALUES (5);
 INSERT INTO tblData1 (Col1) VALUES (5);
```

Here is the `UPDATE` query that you need:

```
UPDATE tblData1
SET Col2 = cnt.aValue
FROM (
    SELECT 
        id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col1) AS aValue
    FROM
        tblData1
) cnt
WHERE tblData1.id = cnt.id
```

Here is the result

[image]